# desktop entry of Unity

Tags: fedora, desktop, unity

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Unity
Comment=Unipro UGENE is a cross-platform visual environment for DNA and protein sequence analysis.
Exec=/home/istiak/Downloads/UnityHub%20.AppImage
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/32/access.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Development;
```

I found above source code from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/282187/1166068). [Here also](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).I was trying as [he was doing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yzEyZR2ktI). But, [image]

When I had pasted it there. I couldn't find any Desktop Entry.[image]

I am not sure what the error is cause, it is first time I am trying to create desktop entry....

Note : I don't want to use [`Alacarte`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103068/1166068)

[image]

[image]
I noticed that I am getting red texts on `Categories`. I am not sure it is error message or not...

Comment: In the `exec` field, that `%20` you've got in the appimage name seems a bit suspicious. Is there a space in the name or the name literally includes `%20`?

Comment: @Krackout No!! it doesn't include. Look I have added a picture...

Comment: So, correct the executable name. Type in or even better copy and paste the exact path-name.

Comment: @Krackout I did by copy and paste the file. When I did this I found `x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/istiak/Downloads/UnityHub%20.AppImage
`. I have removed `%20` but, desktop entry isn't showing

Comment: So, I had removed `x-special/nautilus-clipboard copy file://` from that path.. then, added to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious from the picture you added, the name includes a space, it's `UnityHub .AppImage`. That's why `%20` is added, it's a representation of space in URL encoding. So rename it to `UnityHub.AppImage` (remove the space before the dot), correct the name of the appimage in `exec` and you'll be able to locate and execute the app.

Comment: did it but, desktop entry isn't showing

Comment: Here's my path `/home/istiak/Downloads/UnityHub.AppImage` now..

Comment: try to change permissions of .desktop file, to make it executable. `chmod ugo+x ~/.local/share/applications/Unity.desktop`

Comment: It's working... I noticed...